# Topologies on a polynomial ring

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ denote the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over a field $k$ (I do not mind to assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$, for simplicity).
I wish to find some (all?) topologies on $R$; for example, I am familiar with 
the [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology) and with the
[$I$-adic topology or Krull topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(algebra)).

In particular, I have found [this](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1983v044n04ABEH000975/pdf) article in Russian by Arnautov and Mihalev, but I do not know Russian (and the translation from google is not so clear to me).

Please, can someone tell what are the main results 
of Arnautov and Mihalev, or/and bring any topologies on $R$ (other than the two I have mentioned above)?

**Edit:** I wonder if there exists a topology on $R$ which involves the degrees (or the $x_i$-degrees) of polynomials .

Comment: The Zariski topology is not a topology on a commutative ring $A$, but rather the set $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ of prime ideals of $A$.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course..I meant that I am interested in topologies that are related/connected to a given polynomial ring (preferably a topology on the ring itself).